# Almost-sure convergence implies convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

> Let $X$ be a random variable and $\left\{X_{n}\right\}$ be a sequence of random variables on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Prove that $X_n \to X$ a.s. implies $X_n \to X$ in probability.

Could you check if my attempt is correct?

---

It suffices to prove that $$\mathbb P(|X_n-X| > 1/m) \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty, \quad m \in \mathbb N^*.$$

Notice that $$\{\omega \mid X_n (\omega) \to X (\omega)\} = \bigcap_{m \in \mathbb N^*} \bigcup_{N \in \mathbb N} \bigcap_{n \ge N} \{ \omega | X_n (\omega) - X (\omega) | \le 1/m \}.$$

Because $\mathbb P( \{\omega \mid X_n (\omega) \to X (\omega)\} )=1$, we have $$\mathbb P \left ( \bigcup_{N \in \mathbb N} \bigcap_{n \ge N} \{ \omega \mid | X_n (\omega) - X (\omega) | \le 1/m \} \right ) = 1, \quad m \in \mathbb N^*$$

and thus

$$\begin{aligned}
&\mathbb P (\limsup_n  \{ \omega \mid | X_n (\omega) - X (\omega) | > 1/m \}) \\
={} &\mathbb P \left ( \bigcap_{N \in \mathbb N} \bigcup_{n \ge N} \{ \omega \mid | X_n (\omega) - X (\omega) | > 1/m \} \right ) = 0, \quad m \in \mathbb N^*.
\end{aligned}$$

It follows that $$\begin{aligned}
&0 \\
={} &\mathbb P (\limsup_n  \{ \omega \mid | X_n (\omega) - X (\omega) | > 1/m \}) \\
\ge {} &\limsup_n \mathbb P (  \{ \omega \mid | X_n (\omega) - X (\omega) | > 1/m \} \\
\ge {} &\lim_n \mathbb P (  \{ \omega \mid | X_n (\omega) - X (\omega) | > 1/m \} \\
= {} &\lim_n \mathbb P (| X_n - X | > 1/m).
\end{aligned}$$

The result then follows.

Comment: Imo some steps need to be justified. Like why $\mathbb P(\bigcup\ldots)=1$ holds from $\mathbb P(X_n\to X)=1$ and why is $\mathbb P(\limsup\{\ldots\})\ge\limsup_n\:\mathbb P(\{\ldots\})$. Otherwise it looks good! (There is a quicker proof of this fact using Fatou lemma/dominated convergence once we know that convergence in probability means $\mathbb E[\min(|X_n-X|,1)]\to0$.)

Comment: @nejimban I showed the first fact [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4266492/prove-that-omega-mid-x-n-omega-to-x-omega-is-measurable). The inequality was proved in my class.

Comment: You are also using that $\mathbb P(\bigcap A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P(A_n)$ for a non-increasing sequence of events, aren't you?

Comment: @nejimban I only use $\mathbb P (\bigcap_{m \in \mathbb N^*} \bigcup_{N \in \mathbb N} \bigcap_{n \ge N} A_{n,m}) = 1 \implies \mathbb P (\bigcup_{N \in \mathbb N} \bigcap_{n \ge N} A_{n,m}) = 1$ for all $m \in \mathbb N^*$.

Comment: Right, this is obvious. And I guess the $\mathbb P(\limsup\{\ldots\})\ge\limsup_n\:\mathbb P(\{\ldots\})$ bit is (reverse) Fatou lemma.