# Brezis' exercise 4.14: Vitali theorem

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

I'm trying to solve below exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Exercise 4.14** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$. Let $f,f_n$ be real-valued measurable functions such that $(f_n) \subset L^p(\Omega)$ where $p \in [1, \infty)$ and that $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. Assume that for each $\varepsilon >0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $\sup_n \int_A |f_n|^p < \varepsilon$ for every $A \in \mathcal F$ with $\mu(A) < \delta$. Prove that $f_n \to f$ in $L^p(\Omega)$.

Could you confirm if my below proof is fine?

---

**My attempt** It suffices to prove that $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^p(\Omega)$. We fix $\varepsilon >0$. There is $\delta>0$ such that $\sup_n \int_A |f_n|^p < \varepsilon 2^{-p}$ for every $A \in \mathcal F$ with $\mu(A) < \delta$. By [Egorov theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4672714/brezis-exercise-4-14-egorov-theorem) (where $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$ is needed), there is $A \in \mathcal F$ such that $\mu(A) < \delta$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $A^c := \Omega \setminus A$. There is $N >0$ such that for all $m,n \ge N$,
$$
\begin{align}
& \sup_{\omega \in A^c} |f_n(\omega) - f_m (\omega)| \\
\le{} & \sup_{\omega \in A^c} |f_n(\omega) - f (\omega)| + \sup_{\omega \in A^c} |f_m (\omega) - f (\omega)| \\
<{} &\varepsilon.
\end{align}
$$

We have
$$
\|f_n-f_m\|_p^p = \int_A |f_n-f_m|^p + \int_{A^c} |f_n-f_m|^p.
$$

For all $a,b \in \mathbb R$,
$$
|a+b|^p \le (2 \max\{a,b\})^p = 2^p (\max\{a,b\})^p \le 2^p(|a|^p+|b|^p).
$$

Then for all $m,n \ge N$,
$$
\begin{align}
\|f_n-f_m\|_p^p &\le 2^p \int_A (|f_n|^p + |f_m|^p) + \int_{A^c} |f_n-f_m|^p \\
&\le 2^p (\varepsilon 2^{-p+1}) + \varepsilon \\
&= 3 \varepsilon.
\end{align}
$$

This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only error I see might just be a typo, but $|a+b| \leq 2\max\{a, b\}$ should actually be $|a+b| \leq 2\max\{|a|,|b|\}.$

There are some other things I'd change, but it's mostly for flavor (e.g. there's really no mathematical reason to use $\sup_n \int_A |f_n|^p < \varepsilon 2^{-p}$ rather than just $\sup_n \int_A |f_n|^p < \varepsilon$)