# If $\Vert f \Vert_p < \infty$ for some $1 < p < \infty$ prove that $\lim_{t\to \infty} t^{-(1-1/p)} \int_0^t f(x) \, dx =0$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lp-spaces

**Question:** Suppose $f \colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable so that $\Vert f \Vert_p < \infty$ for some $1 < p < \infty$. Prove that
$$\lim_{t\to \infty} t^{-(1-1/p)} \int_0^t f(x) \, dx =0$$.

**My attempt:** I am able to show that $\limsup_{t \to \infty} t^{-(1-1/p)} \int_0^t f(x) \, dx \leq \Vert f \Vert_{p}$. Is there anyway I can continue with this problem?

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: I think using the Hölder inequality will help.

Comment: @MaximilianSimon I have used Hölder inequality to obtain the following inequality $t^{-(1-1/p)}\int_0^t f(x)\, dx \leq \Vert f \Vert_p$. Should i use a different constant instead?

Comment: I havent fully thought it through but maybe split the integral into $\int_0^{t_0}f+\int_{t_0}^tf$ where $t_0$ is large such that the $L^p$-norm of $f$ is small on $[t_0,\infty)$. With the prefactor the first part goes to zero and you can apply your Hölder-argument on the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a "functional analysis" approach.

---

Let $q$ be the Hölder conjugate of $p$, i.e., $(1/p) + (1/q) = 1$. Let $g_n (x) := n^{-1/q} 1_{(0, n]} (x)$ for $x \in (0, \infty)$. Then $g_n \in L^q ((0, \infty); \mathbb R)$ with $\|g_n\|_q =1$ for $n \ge 1$.  Clearly, $g_n \to 0$ everywhere. By Brezis' [exercise 4.16.1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4673156/brezis-exercise-4-16-1), $g_n \to 0$ in the weak topology $\sigma (L^q, L^p)$. Then $\int g_n f \to 0$. The claim then follows.

Answer (score 2):

The space $\mathcal{C}_{00}([0,\infty))$ is dense in $L_p$. Given $\varepsilon>0$ choose $\phi\in \mathcal{C}_{00}([0,\infty))$ such that
$\|f-\phi\|_p<\varepsilon$. Then, by Holder's inequality,
$$\int^t_0|f-\phi|\leq t^{1/q}\varepsilon$$ where $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$ (since $1<p<\infty$, so is $q$).
Suppose $\operatorname{supp}(\phi)\subset[0,a]$. Then
$$\int^t_0|\phi|\leq \|\phi\|_\infty a$$
for $t>a$. Putting things together
$$t^{-1/q}\int^t_0|f|\leq t^{-1/q}\Big(\int^t_0|f-\phi|+\int^t_0|\phi|\Big)\leq \varepsilon+t^{-1/q}\|\phi\|_\infty a$$
Letting $t\rightarrow\infty$ yields
$$\limsup_{t\rightarrow\infty}t^{-1/p}\int^t_0|f|\leq\varepsilon$$
The conclusion follows from this.

Comment: Thank you, great answer!